# How can I configure gcc that oneself find required my own static library?

Tags: gcc, static-libraries, header-files, configure

I have my own library **libname.a** in /usr/local/lib and header **nameheader.h** in /usr/local/include. I can compile code with `gcc code.c -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -llibname -o code.o` But, if I try to build code without these options, gcc return an error. Why?

How can I tell to gcc where library and header located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through the below link it describes all process with example code.

http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html

Comment: Thank you, for link! Question closed.

Comment: @Jan Close the Question. Only you can do that by clicking the TICK icon.